# Resharper and Moq Returns method

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, moq

I have a simple mocked class longRunningLibrary I want the method Returns from Moq to output some text ("This method...") which you can see in the following part of code :

```
 _longRunningLibrary
   .Setup(lrl => lrl.RunForALongTime(30))
   .Returns("This method has been mocked!");
```

So.. I want this text To be outputted inside the Unit Test Sessions part of resharper, but I can't do it. How to proceed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) you can do like this:

```
[Test]
public void MoqSample()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ILongRunner>();
    mock.Setup(lr => lr.RunForALongTime(It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns("This method has been mocked!");
    ILongRunner longRunner = mock.Object;
    Console.WriteLine(longRunner.RunForALongTime(1));
    Assert.AreEqual("This method has been mocked!", longRunner.RunForALongTime(2));
    Assert.Pass(longRunner.RunForALongTime(3));
}

public interface ILongRunner
{
    string RunForALongTime(int i);
}
```

You can use Console.WriteLine(...) when using the R# testrunner, not sure about when using VS.

The Assert.Pass(...) prints a Success: message

Comment: Thank you Johan I'll use that for now. I also made a similar question on R# forum.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a callback:

```
_longRunningLibrary
   .Setup(lrl => lrl.RunForALongTime(30))
   .Returns("This method has been mocked!")
   .Callback<int>( p => Console.WriteLine("Called with: {0}", p);
```